# Manipulating text in an XML element

Tags: xml, xslt

In my XSL document I have this:

```
<xsl:if test="notification_data/incoming_request/note != ''">
<tr>
<td><h2><b>@@request_note@@: </b> <xsl:value-of select="notification_data/incoming_request/note"/></h2></td>
</tr>
</xsl:if>
```

Where the text in the XML note element is actually three pieces of data jammed together, separated by ||. It's coming in this way by our vendor.

```
<note>||Christie, James||1234567||Lutheran College</note>
```

Is there a way, from within this same XSL document, to parse out these three pieces of data and choose what to print on the letter?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What version of XSLT? If 2.0+, you could use `tokenize(.,'\|\|')[string()]`. Then you could use a positional predicate to select the token you need. For example, if you wanted the second token in your example (`1234567`) you'd use `(tokenize(.,'\|\|')[string()])[2]`.

Comment: And in XSLT 1.0 you can nest `substring-before()` and `substring-after()` functions to extract the wanted token.

Comment: Another consideration, in addition to Daniel's and Michael's, is whether the order of the data elements in your `<note>` elements is always the same.  Can you safely assume that the order is ＊always＊ `||NAME||NUMBER||ORGANIZATION`?  If so, then parsing is relatively simple, as Daniel and Michael have listed above.  However, if you _cannot_ safely assume regular ordering of the data items, then things get messy.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you so much! I'm using XSLT 1.0 so I used the nested substring-before and substring-after to solve this. For anyone who is interested:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(notification_data/incoming_request/note,'||'),'||')"/> - <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(substring-after(substring-after(notification_data/incoming_request/note,'||'),'||'),'||')"/>
```

Resulted in:

```
Christie,James - Lutheran College
```

which is what we wanted to print. And yes, the order of the data elements will always be the same. thanks again!